# How to Update Using Join (Linked Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, outer-join

I want to match the data between 2 databases.
I have 2 Databases. Aa and Bb, and I want to compare Aa to Bb. Database Bb is in linked server

I have join code like this

```
SELECT
B.Employee_Name, B.Employee_NIP, B.DomainName, A.NAMA, A.NIP,
A.StatusEmployee, A.ActiveStatus
FROM
[SERVER-B].Bb.dbo.employee_hierar AS B RIGHT OUTER JOIN
Bb AS B ON B.NIP = A.Employee_NIP
```

and I want update A.StatusEmployee from Y to N if there is NULL data on B.Employee_Name and B.Employee_NIP

note:
SQLServer

Please Advice

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `join`.  Something like:

```
update a
    set StatusEmployee = 'N'
from bb a LEFT JOIN
     [SERVER-B].Bb.dbo.employee_hierar b
    on B.NIP = A.Employee_NIP
where b.EmployeeName is null and b.Employee_NIP is null and
      a.StatusEmployee = 'Y';
```

Answer (score 0):

This is same to update multi tables in one database. Standard sql should be written like this:

```
UPDATE A
SET StatusEmployee = "N"
WHERE NOT EXISTS
( SELECT * FROM B WHERE B.NIP = A.Employee_NIP )
```